# Serre relations in PBW basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I want show that when expressed in a PBW ordered basis, the Serre relations for a Lie Algebra become $0=0$.
I am have trouble understanding what this question want. I think it just mean that Serre relations hold in universal enveloping algebra?

The Serre relations is $ad(E_{i})^{1-A_{ij}}E_{j}=ad(F_{i})^{1-A_{ij}}F_{j}=0$ for $i\neq j$, where $\{E_{i},F_{i},H_{j}:1\leq i\leq r\}$ are generators and $A$ is a Cartan matrix. So I think showing Serre relations become $0=0$ just mean showing $ad(E_{i})^{1-A_{ij}}E_{j}=0$ and same for $F_{i}$, is this right?

A PBW basis is a basis of Universal Enveloping Algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$ for $\mathfrak{g}$ which consist of monomial of form $x_{1}^{k_{1}}...x_{n}^{k_{n}}$ where $x_{1}<...<x_{n}$ are elements of ordered basis of $\mathfrak{g}$.

I think I have to order basis consisting of $\{E_{i},F_{i},H_{j}:1\leq i\leq r\}$ and nested commutator, but not sure how.

I also know $A$ is cartan matrix so I find $1-A_{ij}\in\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Looking at $ad(E_{i})^{l}E_{j}$ for $l\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ and using $[x,y]=xy-yx$ in universal enveloping algebra I try to show this expression zero but do not manage.

Please clarify what the question means or give a hint, thankyou.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I understand Serre relation enforce finiteness because they say that a certain number of nested commutator is zero. I also undertand your point that in universal enveloping algebra we do not have finiteness. So  it does make sense that the Serre relation should define no restriction on universal enveloping algebra.I still not sure on how to explictly show this though, could you possibly elaborate? Thank you very much.

Comment: If you know already that your Lie algebra is semisimple, then you can know which root strings occur and which do not. With this knowledge, perhaps your expression can reduce to zero.